# Cassandra disk io

Tags: io, cassandra, disk

Hey was wondering if anyone could help me, i'm getting to know cassandra but I was curious and wanted to measure how many disk I/O's were occuring when i was reading from column families.

I looked at opscentre profiler but the only metric i could find was DIsk Utilisation but from what i understand this is the time the CPU spends doing disk I/O so im guessing its measuring stuff like context switch time. However since it does this i thought maybe there must be a point when cassandra realises it does have to go to disk then i could just put a counter there.

The other option could be put two timestamps round the read call and if it's in the order of ms then i know its a disk read. However i'm not entirely sure where the system call is, i thought i located it in RandomAccessReader in the reBuffer() method (int n = super.read(buffer, read, buffer.length - read);) however it doesn't seem that way when I query the column families.

In short, any ideas on how to figure out the number of disk I/O's that are occuring?

Answer (score 1):

`iostat -m 1 -x` prints out various statistics for your disk, including number of read operations per second.  If you have dedicated disks for Cassandra this will tell you the total number of read I/Os, but this includes compaction.  If there is no compaction running then it will measure just your read operations.

It is hard to get the number of actual disk I/Os by measuring syscalls because, even if Cassandra issues a read syscall, it may be read from the filesystem cache and not actually touch disk.

In the worse case, Cassandra will do 2 I/Os for each read.  One to find the offset (if there is no offset in the keycache and the index file isn't in cache), and the other to retrieve the data from the SSTable (if the SSTable isn't in cache).

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. I'll try using iostat as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

1- for individual node disk IOPs

Put below script in a .sh file and schedule it to run:

```
#!/bin/bash

 `echo date` 
  printf "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t nodetool info Information\n"
  printf "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t ***********************\n\n" 
 `echo nodetool info` 


  printf "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t iostat -c Information\n" 
  printf "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t ***********************\n\n" 
 `echo iostat -c` 

  printf "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t iostat -x -m 60 Information\n" 
  printf "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t *****************************\n\n" 
 `echo iostat -x -m 60 -d 1`

  printf "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t vmstat -s -S m 60 Information\n" 
  printf "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t *******************************\n\n"
 `echo vmstat -s -S m 60` 

  printf "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t nodetool cfstats Information\n"
  printf "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t **************************************************\n" 
 `echo nodetool cfstats` 

  printf "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t nodetool  tpstats\n" 
  printf "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t *************************************\n\n" 
 `echo nodetool tpstats` 
  printf "\n\n" 
  printf "___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\n\n"
  echo 'END'
```

2- for network IOPs

Install Ganglia, it has some nice charts and have real-time monitoring